# Pods getting recreated every 2 mins after trying to pull the images of size more than 1 GB. But not completing

Tags: docker, kubernetes, jenkins-kubernetes

I am trying to pull and run the images which are of a size more than 1 GB in Kubernetes pods. After 2 minutes, pods getting destroyed and recreating and the same issue is happening in a loop. 
Below is what I am getting while running ///kubectl get pods

```
NAME                                                             READY   STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
dynamic-agent-fe7b9f8e-bce6-471b-a6b9-26cc52b02bba-4nxcd-psngk   0/3     ContainerCreating   0          <invalid>


Events:
  Type    Reason     Age   From                      Message
  ----    ------     ----  ----                      -------
  Normal  Scheduled  92s   default-scheduler         Successfully assigned default/dynamic-agent-fe7b9f8e-bce6-471b-a6b9-26cc52b02bba-4nxcd-qvg8c to k8sworker1-test
  Normal  Pulling    41s   kubelet, k8sworker1-test  pulling image "docker-all.xxx.xxx.net/sap/ppiper/node-browsers:v3"
```

After the above step, it continues to pull for 120 seconds after that k8s killing the pod and recreating it again same pulling process repeats...

Comment: add kubelet logs from the node where the pod is scheduled

Comment: If you can add more information, this would help as well. Did you try to download the image locally? Is there a proxy in front of the registry, maybe there's a misconfiguration. What is the error message you get, while downloading it locally. Is the image public available, that someone of us can test it?

Let us know, what you already tried.

Comment: If you can reduce the image size that will help things a lot; 1 GB is an informal practical upper bound on the size of an image, or else you'll run into things like the timeout issues you're encountering.  If you have a full C toolchain (`apt-get install build-essential`) rebuilding it using a multi-stage Dockerfile can be a helpful approach.

Comment: Hi sorry for the late reply.. actuall these pods are running in test environment cluster however if I am changing to prod cluster the pods are not running without any issue. So I spot it is a capacity issue, but however I could see there is enough diskspace is available in kubernetes test environment cluster I am not sure what parameter is overloading when the containers are pulled

Comment: @DavidMaze I already informed the team to use less weight images, but they want to scale up the infrastructure.. I am not sure which parameter I have to check to scale the capacity in test environment cluster where these pods are running fine in prod environment cluster I will post the kubectl describe nodes logs here..

Comment: can you provide logs from journalctl -u kubelet ?